# How to Post data to an external API with user input(radio button & dropdown menu) using Angular 7/8

Tags: angular, typescript, tomcat8, angular8

I used this site (https://www.positronx.io/angular-8-httpclient-http-tutorial-build-consume-restful-api/) to follow 
a HTTP Post Tutorial to help with my own side project 
but the result is that I am receiving a 500 error. 
Ultimately, I want submit user input to Post to my API.

I am relatively new to Angular so any guidance as to how set this up would be greatly appreciated.

```
http service file:-------------------------------
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Dumpsters } from 'src/app/dumpsterFolder/dumpsterObjects/dumpster';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  //CREATE: /** POST: add a new dumpster to the server */ 
  createNewDumpster(data):Observable<Dumpsters>{
    return this.http.post<Dumpsters>(this.addNewDumpsterUrl, 
    JSON.stringify(data), this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.errorHandl)
    )
  }
-------------------------------------------------------
component file: ---------------------------------------
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from '../../http.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Dumpsters } from 'src/app/dumpsterFolder/dumpsterObjects/dumpster';

export class AddNewDumpsterComponent implements OnInit {

  newDumpsterForm: FormGroup;
  newDumpster: Dumpsters[];


  ngOnInit() {
   this.addNewDumpster();
  }

  constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private router: Router,
    public httpService: HttpService
  ){ }

  addNewDumpster() {
    this.newDumpsterForm = this.fb.group({
      dumpsterSize:Number [''],
      dumpsterHealth:Number ['']
    })
  }

  submitForm() {
    this.httpService.createNewDumpster(this.newDumpsterForm.value).subscribe(res => {
      console.log('A New Dumpster Was Added!')
      this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/dumpsterList')) 
    });
  }
}
----------------------------------------------------------------------
component HTML file:--------------------------------------------------
<div class="container">

  <h3>Add New Dumpster</h3>

<!-- My code based on the online example.  -->
<form [formGroup]="newDumpsterForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" novalidate>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Dumpster Sizes</legend>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check">

          <input type="radio" formControlName="dumpsterSize" value="1">

          <label class="form-check-label" >
            10 yd
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check ">

          <input type="radio" formControlName="dumpsterSize" value="2">

          <label class="form-check-label" >
            15 yd
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="radio" formControlName="dumpsterSize" value="3">
          <label class="form-check-label" >
            20 yd
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check ">
          <input type="radio" formControlName="dumpsterSize" value="4">
          <label class="form-check-label" >
            30 yd
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 ">
      <span>Rank Dumpster's Condition</span>
      <select class="form-control healthRankDropDown" formControlName="dumpsterHealth">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7 and Greater Needs Attention!</option>
        <option value="8">8 Needs Attention!</option>
        <option value="9">9 Needs Attention!</option>
        <option value="10">10 Needs Attention!</option>
      </select>

    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div class="form-field">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      Add New Dumpster
    </button>
  </div>

</form>

</div>

I am expecting to pass two values to the post method to post to the API.
```

Comment: I removed some code to try to only include code relevant to the question. Also, I am able to successfully post data to the database using Postman.

Comment: What does the call look like that Angular ends up sending to the API that is causing the 500 error?

Comment: @DanGorman If I understand your question correctly, this is the call Angular ends up sending to the API that causes the 500 error.

Comment: Do you mean what does the post method look like or what is the error message?

Comment: submitForm() {
    this.httpService.createNewDumpster(this.newDumpsterForm.value).subscribe(res => {
      console.log('A New Dumpster Was Added!')
      this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/dumpsterList')) 
    });
  }

Comment: @Dominic, a error 500 is an error that indicate the API **in server** has an error, e.g. can update the dbs because not found, you has a divided by 0, you throw an exception...

Comment: No I had meant that Angular will interpret your post call into a web request to the API i.e. www.yourapi.com/new?id=12345&count=321 this should be viewable in the console of your browser as well as other details of the request. My thought is that the request may be malformed. Eliseo is correct this may need to be troubleshot on the API side because the API is receiving it, though it cannot pocess the request for whatever reason.

Comment: I just want to say your advice was really helpful and I figured it out, the request was malformed. The property name I declared in Angular did not match the instance variable I declared in Java. It seems to always be the little things! Thank you guys! @Dan Gorman

Comment: @Eliseo Thank you